# How to access recorded meetings in Microsoft teams via API

Tags: microsoft-teams

we want to access meeting recordings from Microsoft team meetings after the meeting finishes. 
How to achieve that? Is there an API/package that does that?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Meeting recorded within teams call stored in Microsoft Stream. Currently there is no API to access these meeting but you can take a look [Real Time Media calls and meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts) to access meeting frame by frame.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft announced "API-level access to meeting recordings" in september 2020, so that's finally going to happen, but so far the API docs do not show any signs of availability.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-blog/a-new-vision-for-microsoft-stream/ba-p/1686304

[edit] it seems that the "API-level access" is about the Drive/Sharepoint APIs that are coming, and that should allow to download the files in a generic, albeit per-user way (e.g. list all mp4 files in Drive and download them).

The second way to achieve this is to use the compliance recording API: https://tomtalks.blog/2020/05/microsoft-teams-policy-based-compliance-recording-api-is-now-generally-available/